# ffmpeg when asked to map a .mov file's streams 0,1,3 actually maps streams 0,1,2

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe, .mov

I'm trying the following:

Start with `in.mov` which has 4 streams 0:0 - 0:3.

Audio, Video, Data (unknown), and mJpeg.

Trying to map 0:0, 0:1, and 0:3 into `out013.mov`.

`ffmpeg -i in.mov -map 0 -map -0:2 -c copy out013.mov`

or

`ffmpeg -i in.mov -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c copy out013.mov`

ffmpeg tells me that 3 streams are mapped:

```
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:2 (copy)
```

ffprobe disagrees. According to it what really happened was:

```
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
```

"*Who needs a thumbnail image anyways, screw it!*" I said. "*Let's just get rid of the data.*"

`ffmpeg -i out013.mov -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c copy out01.mov`

ffmpeg tells me that 2 streams are mapped:

```
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
```

ffprobe disagrees. According to it what really happened was:

```
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
```

Seems like I can't rid myself of that data stream (0:2).

Below is the output from the ffprobe and ffmpeg for the first scenario.

Any ideas?

---

`ffprobe in.mov`

```
ffprobe version 2023-09-07-git-9c9f48e7f2-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
  libavcodec     60. 26.100 / 60. 26.100
  libavformat    60. 11.100 / 60. 11.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.101 / 60.  2.101
  libavfilter     9. 11.100 /  9. 11.100
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023b088f3300] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'in.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2023-08-22T21:23:09.000000Z
    title           : Redacted
    com.apple.quicktime.displayname: Redacted
    com.apple.quicktime.title: Redacted
  Duration: 00:00:30.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 152583 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-08-22T21:23:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Video: prores (Standard) (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 150213 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-08-22T21:23:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Stream #0:2[0x3](und): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-08-22T21:23:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Time Code
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Stream #0:3[0x0]: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

---

`ffmpeg -i in.mov -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:3 -c copy out013.mov`

```
ffmpeg version 2023-09-07-git-9c9f48e7f2-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
  libavcodec     60. 26.100 / 60. 26.100
  libavformat    60. 11.100 / 60. 11.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.101 / 60.  2.101
  libavfilter     9. 11.100 /  9. 11.100
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001f92e383880] stream 0, timescale not set
[aist#0:0/pcm_s24le @ 000001f92e50f400] Guessed Channel Layout: stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'in.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2023-08-22T21:23:09.000000Z
    title           : Redacted
    com.apple.quicktime.displayname: Redacted
    com.apple.quicktime.title: Redacted
  Duration: 00:00:30.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 152583 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-08-22T21:23:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Video: prores (Standard) (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 150213 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-08-22T21:23:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Stream #0:2[0x3](und): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-08-22T21:23:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Time Code
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Stream #0:3[0x0]: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
Output #0, mov, to 'out013.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    com.apple.quicktime.title: Redacted
    title           : Redacted
    com.apple.quicktime.displayname: Redacted
    encoder         : Lavf60.11.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-08-22T21:23:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Video: prores (Standard) (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 150213 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-08-22T21:23:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Stream #0:2: Video: mjpeg (Progressive) (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[out#0/mov @ 000001f92e398340] video:550881kB audio:8446kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
frame=  900 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lq=-1.0 size=  559116kB time=00:00:30.02 bitrate=152567.6kbits/s speed= 117x
```

---

`ffprobe out013.mov`

```
ffprobe version 2023-09-07-git-9c9f48e7f2-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
  libavcodec     60. 26.100 / 60. 26.100
  libavformat    60. 11.100 / 60. 11.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.101 / 60.  2.101
  libavfilter     9. 11.100 /  9. 11.100
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out013.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    title           : Redacted
    encoder         : Lavf60.11.100
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Duration: 00:00:30.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 152523 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2]: Video: prores (Standard) (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 150213 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : FFMP
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Stream #0:2[0x4](eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

Comment: The data stream is a timecode track. In addition to *not* mapping it, add `-write_tmcd false`

Comment: Thank you Gyan, alas, this does not work. The timecode track is not written, but so does the third (mjpeg) track.    `ffmpeg -i in.mov -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:3 -write_tmcd false -c copy out013.mov`

Comment: `Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:2 (copy)`

Comment: `Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2]: Video: prores (Standard) (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 150213 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : FFMP
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422`